# Android 2.3 Google Maps Missing Resource maps_watermark_dark.png

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that has [minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) set to 9. 
The application compiles and runs, but when it's time to display a Google Map it crashes with

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi-v4/maps_watermark_dark.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02027c
```

Everything points to a resource missing in the play services lib.

I'm not using proguard, shrinkResources or resConfigs.

The device is a samsung/GT-S5360L/GT-S5360L:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD

Here's the relevant part of the `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'    

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 21
        minSdkVersion 9
        versionCode 476
        versionName "4.7.6"
    }
}    
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

And here's the stacktrace I'm getting:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(10297): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(10297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020578)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.safertaxi.driver/driver.activities.driving.ActivityDriving}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at driver.activities.driving.ActivityDriving.onCreate(ActivityDriving.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(10297): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi-v4/maps_watermark_dark.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02027c
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.cl.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.cl.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.el.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ab.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aa.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.x.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at driver.fragments.maps.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime(10297): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi-v4/maps_watermark_dark.png
E/AndroidRuntime(10297):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset
```

---

**EDIT #1:**

Issue still persists after:

- Upgraded to targetSdkVersion 21
- Upgraded to Google Play Services 6.1.17
- Installed Google Play Services on the phone: 6.5.87

---

**EDIT #2:**

This is how the map is currently loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
        android:name="driver.fragments.maps.FragmentMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public final class FragmentMap extends SupportMapFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        ...
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT #3:**

Apparently the issue is fixed by updating the version of Google Play Services installed on the device to 6.5.99. However, I can not confirm this as the device that experienced the issue broke down. I can not reproduce the issue as I can not reinstall 6.5.87 on a new device because the latest Google Play version is 6.5.99.

Comment: what happens if you upgrade to a newer version of google play services

Comment: I'm getting the following native exception when upgrade to play services 6.5 http://pastie.org/9790387

Comment: First I would suggest to perform checkJNI: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html. Because it seems to be a native code error. See if you can track it through this utility.

Comment: Please disregard the native crash. It was related to other library crashing first. I have removed the link from the main question for clarity

Comment: Please file a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/ include relevant information and sample code.

Comment: Can you post the activity (and fragment) code you're using to display the map?

Comment: @KayAnn Thanks for the link. I have created the issue ( https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7562 ) @ user3249477 I have updated the question with the relevant code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Google Maps bug tracker, this is an obsolete issue as it no longer happens on newer Google Play services versions.

For more information visit:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7562

Answer (score 1):

I see similar problem occurring [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914521/2841101). Here many explanations are mentioned but I suggest checking the screen compatibility mode. It looks more probable as you have already taken care of min SDK.